# Why Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName returns Null always

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
println Jenkins.getInstance() def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(name, AbstractItem) println 'Job: ' + job
```

returns Null always.
This function works well with Jenkins version 2.122 but breaks with 2.190.

Output :

```
hudson.model.Hudson@2a1b0795
[Pipeline] echo
Job: null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getConfigFile() on null object
```

Need help to understand and debug

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getInstance()
```